# Fetching Next and previous data on button click

Tags: java

I am new in java, i want to fetch next and previous row of database  on button click of next and previous button respectiely.

```
private void btnNextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    st = con.createStatement();
    for(i=1;i<=5;++i){
      rs = st.executeQuery("select ID,EName from attendence where ID="+(i));
      while(rs.next()) {
        t1.setText(rs.getString("ID"));
      }        
     }
```

i am not understanding how to iterate and fetch next row and on previous button click it needs to fetch previous row .
i think i need to maintain counter to store current position.
but how to do that .Please help how to code on Next and previous button.and when first row comes previous should be get unable. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Use 'rs.previous()' maybe? You do not need any counters. next() and previous() are all you need!

Comment: When you click these buttons (next and previous), the result set is reloaded from the database and the cursor is set before the first row. You may need to have a separate method (probably called on load) to initialize `ResultSet` only once which you can use in the methods which are invoked, when the next and the previous buttons are clicked. Also, your query statement is wide open for SQL attacks. Make use of `PreparedStatement` to mitigate them.

Comment: @Tiny can you provide me sample code?

Comment: Sure I could but sorry, I'm currently not much familiar with swing/awt.

Comment: @Tiny ok no problem but code about next and previous?

Comment: You could initialize the result set object `rs`, when your window is loaded (I don't know what that component is named but it may be `javax.swing.JPanel`, `javax.swing.JFrame` or whatever). Once `rs` is initialized, you could just use `rs.next()` in the method which invoked, when the next button is clicked and `rs.previous()` in the method which is called, when the previous button is clicked. In any case, error handling should be done precisely. When the cursor is moved to the last row, it should be moved to the first row and so is for previous. To my guess, this should do what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch all your employee records at once and store them as java object in a List and then you can maintain current index of the displayed employee and move forward and backward using current index.

Note: You can fetch records in chunks instead of all at once to improve performance as well

Hope this helps.

```
    public class Navigator {

        private List<Employee> employees = null;
        private currentIndex = 0;
        public Navigator(){
           populate employee list here using data base resultset
        }

        public Employee getCurrent() {
                return employees.get(currentIndex):null;
        }

        public Employee getNext() {
                return employees.get(++currentIndex);
        }

        public Employee getPrev(){
                return employees.get(--currentIndex);
        }
    }
```

Then call methods of this class from your button's action performed.